# Correct word for lesson where teacher was replaced by another teacher

Tags: vocabulary

What is the the correct term for a lesson where the teacher was replaced by a different teacher, because he was ill?

Is it called a substitution (lesson)?

Even further: What would a plan of these lessons be called? 
Substitution board?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term for the **actual lesson** BUT when we have a replacement teacher, we do say "We have a substitute teacher today".  I've never heard substitution lesson used before in my school years. I usually just called lessons from substitute teachers "busy work" :P

Comment: @Element115 Thanks. So there is no real word for it? How did you know which replacement teacher you will get?

Comment: I can't say for sure that there's no word for it. One of these intelligent gentleman here may come along with the perfect word. The only thing I could think of is calling it a **substitute** lesson. As for knowing which replacement teacher we would get, the conversation was usually. "Did you hear we have a sub(word we use to abbreviate substitute) in English today?" "No, who's the sub?" "Mr. Jeremy" "Ah, he's the worst".

Comment: Haha I hope so. Thanks for sharing your experience

Comment: I agree with Element115's suggestion (which should probably be an answer).  There is no word for the *lesson*, only a word for the *teacher*, namely "substitute".

Comment: It is the teacher that is a substitute teacher, not the lesson. Usually, they teach ""from the book" and do not have to do a lesson plan at all.

Comment: ^Or in my teachers cases, give a massive packet of worksheets:P

Comment: The teacher, btw, is always called a "substitute," as opposed to "replacement." A *replacement* teacher would be for a regular teacher who is gone for the rest of the school year, or longer. A *substitute* is for a teacher who will be back in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some variation between the American and British use here.

In Britain, when a teacher is away, another teacher *covers* their lesson, and teaches a *cover lesson*. The teacher who is absent should provide *a cover lesson plan* (shortened to "cover").

The cover teacher may be another teacher in the school. Or the school may hire a temporary teacher for the day, called a *supply teacher*

> Have you got Mr Smith's cover? The supply teacher is here and she's covering his year 8 class in period 1.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling the comments into an answer.
In English, there's no specific, or commonly used word to describe a lesson that is being substituted in place of the regular lesson. Instead, we often just refer to it as having a substitute teacher(sometimes abbreviated **sub**). It is the teacher that is substituted, not the lesson. Usually the substitute teachers just **teach from the book** and have no lesson plan at all.
Example:

> "Did you hear we have a sub(titute) in English today?"
>   "No I didn't who is it?"
>   "Mr. Jeremy"
>   "Ah, he's the worst!"